Update README.md via renovate. Use git-tags or gitea-tags as datasource
I would like to update a version mentioned in a README.md file via renovate (v39.50.0). The version depends on a git tag of the same repository. Here an excerpt of the README.md file.
CHART_VERSION=0.1.0
helm show values prometheus-exporters/prometheus-postgres-exporter --version "${CHART_VERSION}" > values.yaml

I configured the following customManager rule, to automatically patch the README.md file:
{
  "description": "Detect helm chart version in README",
  "fileMatch": [
    "^README\\.md$"
  ],
  "matchStrings": [
    "^CHART_VERSION=(?<currentValue>.*)$"
  ],
  "datasourceTemplate": "git-tags",
  "depNameTemplate": "volker.raschek/prometheus-postgres-exporter",
  "packageNameTemplate": "git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/prometheus-postgres-exporter",
  "versioningTemplate": "semver"
}

Nevertheless, renovate is not able to patch the README.md file. Normally I should receive a PR with version 0.2.1.
Instead of "datasourceTemplate": "git-tags" I also tried it with "datasourceTemplate": "gitea-tags", but this also does not work. The examples of how to use the datasource git-tags or gitea-tags with a self-hosted VCS is not very well documented.
Instead of packageNameTemplate I also tried lookupNameTemplate, but without success:
{
  "description": "Detect helm chart version in README",
  "fileMatch": [
    "^README\\.md$"
  ],
  "matchStrings": [
    "^CHART_VERSION=(?<currentValue>.*)$"
  ],
  "datasourceTemplate": "git-tags",
  "depNameTemplate": "volker.raschek/prometheus-postgres-exporter",
  "lookupNameTemplate": "git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/prometheus-postgres-exporter",
  "versioningTemplate": "semver"
}

Has anyone an idea, how to configure a customManager to update a simple README.md with a git-tag version?
